# Is it possible to top up a TMN PT Moche PAYG phone online?

Tags: cellphones, spain, portugal

Can anyone out there let me know if it's possible to top up a TMN Moche PAYG number while abroad in Spain? I would use my PT bank account but I've no money in it.

Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "top up a TMN Moche PAYG"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, no. TMN provides several ways of [recharging your phone](http://www.tmn.pt/portal/site/tmn/menuitem.3d4521ffdeeec3803d21ecd0851056a0/?vgnextoid=03a8691d97723310VgnVCM1000005401650aRCRD) when abroad. Of course some require that you have money in your account so I will not list them.

You can't top up with credit card but you can request temporary credit to TMN.
You can do this with [Krédito service](http://www.tmn.pt/portal/site/tmn/menuitem.25e6144f031ea516da739345851056a0/?vgnextoid=2fd79f9eb7497010VgnVCM1000005401650aRCRD).

An alternative may be using the [Karga service](http://www.tmn.pt/portal/site/tmn/menuitem.25e6144f031ea516da739345851056a0/?vgnextoid=0c7cfaf4cf05df00VgnVCM1000005a01650aRCRD). You may ask a friend of yours to transfer money from his TMN account to yours.

Note: All links are in portuguese. You may want to use google translate or a similar service if you don't understand portuguese.